# Laravel controllers Undefined variable: names

Tags: php, laravel

I get the error `Undefined variable: names` when I try to access the controller.

**Route.php:**

```
Route::get('article', 'ArticleController@showIndex');
```

**ArticleController.php:**

```
class ArticleController extends BaseController{

    public function showIndex(){
        return View::make('hello');
    }

    public function showSingle($articleId){
        return View::make('single');
    }

}
```

**URL:**

```
http://localhost:8080/learning-laravel/article
```

Quite new to laravel, so I am not entirely sure what I'm missing.

Comment: There could be something in your views. Is your root `http://localhost:8080/learning-laravel/` working?

Comment: this has to be something in your view assuming you aren't sending any data to the view in the code you provided.